# Spark Save as Text File grouped by Key

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to save RDD to text file grouped by key, currently I can't figure out how to split the output to multiple files, it seems all the output spanning across multiple keys which share the same partition gets written to the same file. I would like to have different files for each key. Here's my code snippet :

```
JavaPairRDD<String, Iterable<Customer>> groupedResults = customerCityPairRDD.groupByKey();

groupedResults.flatMap(x -> x._2().iterator())
              .saveAsTextFile(outputPath + "/cityCounts");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured how to solve this. Convert RDD to Dataframe and then just partition by key during write.

```
Dataset<Row> dataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(customerRDD, Customer.class);
dataFrame.write()
         .partitionBy("city")
         .text("cityCounts");  // write as text file at file path cityCounts
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using foreachPartition to save each partitions into separate file.

You can develop your code as follows

```
groupedResults.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<Customer>>() {


@Override
public void call(Iterator<Customer> rec) throws Exception {
  FSDataOutputStream fsoutputStream = null;
  BufferedWriter writer = null;

  try {
    fsoutputStream = FileSystem.get(new Configuration()).create(new Path("path1"))
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fsoutputStream)

    while (rec.hasNext()) {
      Customer cust = rec.next();
      writer.write(cust)
    }
  } catch (Exception exp) {
    exp.printStackTrace()
    //Handle exception
  }
  finally {
    // close writer.
  }
}
});
```

Hope this helps.

Ravi

Comment: doesn't seem to work, throws User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable

Comment: Hope that Customer class might not implemented Serializable interface.  Please implement the Serializable interface in Customer class. Still you are facing issues, provide the full error message with stack trace.